# Understanding Primitive Data Types: Storage Capacity/Range of int and float in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, int, type-conversion, primitive-types

I am trying to get a good understanding of Java's primitive data types. I already got a good overview and I understand how signed integer values are stored in Java, and how to tell/calculate the range of a byte-, short-, integer- or long-data type.

So, when looking at the Java data type int I know that it is a 32 bit signed value, thus I can tell exactly how many different "states" a int-type can store and what the range of that datatype is (i.e. 2^32 different states, resulting in a range from -2^31 through +(2^31)-1 or roughly -2e+9 through +2e+9).

When looking at the data type float, however, I need some help. I understand that Java's float data type is a 32 bit type (just like int), thus I would assume that it can also store a total of 2^32 different states. However, when I look at the numbers given in this table (http://www.javacamp.org/javaI/primitiveTypes.html) I don't understand how this data type can store floating point numbers in the range from roughly -3e+38 through 3e+38 (which is already a much wider range than what int can cover) PLUS all the single-precision floating point decimals in between - with just 32 bit.

Can any one please explain how floating point numbers are stored and why it "looks like" it can store more information than int within the same number of bits (which feels pretty much impossible to me)? Maybe you can point me to a good read or show me where I made a logical mistake.

Comment: Have you read [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Comment: anything you heard about mantissa, radix point?

Comment: @SachinVerma: Now I have. Thanks for pointing me to those keywords!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is realizing that a `float` *can't* accurately hold even all the integers in the range -3e+38 to 3e+38. The difference between "adjacent" float values depends on the magnitude: for float values close to 0, the difference between adjacent values; for very large values (positive or negative) the difference can be very large.

Basically a floating point number consists of:

- A sign - positive or negative
- A *mantissa* or significand (see comments below) - a string of binary digits, effectively
- An *exponent* - the number of binary digits to shift the mantissa left or right

The mantissa in a `float` is 23 bits long, and the exponent is 8 bits - so you'll only ever get 23 (or 24 due to normalization) significant bits of information, but they could be shifted left a lot (to form a huge number) or right a lot (to form a tiny number). There are some other details around normalization which are relevant, but that's the basic idea.

See my .NET-oriented but still Java-relevant [article on binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for more information, along with [one by Jeffrey Sax](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/resources/Articles/FPDotNetConceptsAndFormats.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation and pointing me to those reads! That helps a lot!!!

Comment: The preferred term for the fraction portion is “significand” rather than “mantissa”. The IEEE 754 standard uses “significand”. A significand is linear. A mantissa is logarithmic. Mantissas are rarely used anymore since we no longer use books of log tables for computing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I wouldn't claim to understand the difference - but I do note that the JLS uses the term "mantissa" rather than "significand". Will edit to point to your comment though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to forgo all of the bit-twiddling and upls stuff for simplicity. Let's take a look at a 10-digit number in base 10(unsigned in this case but fairly extensible). It can store numbers from 0 to 9999999999. Now, let's take 2 of those digits and turn them to an exponent, like in floating-point. Now, we can go from 1x10<sup>-99</sup> to 99,999,999x<sup>10^99</sup>. Onbiously a much larger range

Note the fact that at the max we lose our smaller digits. For example, 999,999,999,999,999,991 and 999,999,999,999,999,992 would get truncated down in the same way for the 8 digits that aren't the exponent, since those numbers don't fit in 8 digits. They'd both be 999,999,99x10<sup>17</sup>